# find().val() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to get a dynamic hidden input's value inside a jquery data table using find().val() but it returns undefined. How do I make it so that it returns the value of the input?

```
//foreach instantiate
   <input style="display: none;" value="{{$userTable['username']}} - {{$userTable['name']}}" />

//end foreach instantiate
```

jquery trying to get the value of the hidden input.

```
 $.each($("#datacal_table tr"), function(){
        arrTableName.push($(this).find('input').eq(0).val());
      });
```

layout of the table

```
    <table id="datacal_table" 
     class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
       <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Username</th>
           <th>Type</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Computation Sheet Name</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="dctbody">
      //foreach instantiation
       <tr>
      <td id="username_table">
          {{$userTable['username']}} <br>
          {{$userTable['name']}}

       <input style="display: none;" value="{{$userTable['username']}}
     - {{$userTable['name']}}" />
     </td>
    ......<td> values
     <tr>
    //end for each
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Paragraphs `find('p')` do NOT have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find `input` element and not `p` tag. Although [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method is not necessary here since [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returns value of first element.

```
arrTableName.push($(this).find('input').val());
//                           ---^^^^^---

// or more specific to get hidden element
arrTableName.push($(this).find('input:hidden').val());
//                           ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

---

**FYI :** The `input` element is self-closing so `</input>` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise you should look for `tbody` section `tr` elements and in that too for `input` elements. Also there are no `p` elements that you should look for.

```
 $.each($("#datacal_table tbody tr"), function(){
    arrTableName.push($(this).find('input').val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```
 $("#datacal_table > tbody  >").each(function(){
  arrTableName.push($(this).find('input:hidden').val());
  })
```

using the direct children selector (`>`) you will walk over immediate descendents (and not all descendents)